# how can I render a url in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my controller but don't work (when I set redirect_to page1_url works well):

```
render page1_url
```

in my routes.rb I have a url path:

```
get "main/page1"
post "main/page1"
match "page1" => 'main#page1'
```

when I change render in my controller so

```
render 'main/page1'
```

works well but the images in the view not appear, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a name for the route helper using ":as".  This will give you the page1_url helper.

```
 match "page1" => 'main#page1', :as=>"page1"
```

See: [naming routes in the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)